# $location.search issue - angularjs

Tags: angularjs

I have a parent view which have two child view in a single state.

View one have input field.

view two displays results based on what is entered on view one input field, which gets updated in the url using $location.search() , from where param is being taken , passed into an api and 
then the result is displayed in this view.

But this refreshes the whole page. I want to restrict it from refreshing view one but not view two(as it loads data and must change based on input) else whatever is written in view one input text is being erased.

How to restrict view one from getting refreshed on url change?

I am using ui-route

Comment: Provide your work here and perhaps a working model of what you want to do, or at least what is happening. There are many ways to do what you want, perhaps you should re-evaluate how your doing this. Is your current implementation over complicated?

Answer (score 0):

Do the same that you are doing to get this page `onStateChangeStart`.

```
$rootScope.on('onStateChangeStart', function (event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams){

     if(fromState === 'your state name here'){
         // perform if based on your requirement
         // Now try to render the same page with the from or to params based on requirement
     }
});
```

Comment: I have a single state with a parent view having two child view each having a seperate controller

Comment: Refreshing a page means you are restarting the entire app. It definitely reloaded. As your above comment, your toState and fromState both are same. But parameters passed may loose at the time of refresh. So, we can get them from toParams and fromParams